# Java: How to create a specific class instance?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a method with signature

```
<T extends AbstractClass> T method(Class<T> abstractClass)
```

and I cannot modify the signature.

Also I have a string with class name `com.test.MyClass`. Is it possible to create a class by class name to pass to my method?

Something like that

```
Class<? extends AbstractClass> clz = (Class<? extends AbstractClass>) Class.forName(classNameStr);
```

Comment: You can't actually create concrete instances of an abstract class; you'll need something derived from it

Comment: My class name is a concrete class. It's a name of class which extends abstract class.

Comment: @Robert The OP isn't asking how to create an instance of a class given the class name as a `String`. She is asking how to _call the given method_ so it returns an object of the class for which she only has the class name as a `String`. That's my understanding anyway.

Comment: @Barbara You can do something like this: `AbstractClass obj = method((Class<? extends AbstractClass>) Class.forName("com.test.MyClass"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a type safe dynamic class loading, the correct way is:

```
Class<? extends AbstractClass> clz =
    Class.forName(classNameStr).asSubclass(AbstractClass.class);
```

This does not generate “unchecked” warnings as it *is* checked at runtime in the [`asSubclass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass(java.lang.Class)) method and afterwards, e.g. calling `newInstance` an that `Class` is guaranteed to return an instance of `AbstractClass`.

---

So afterwards you can do

```
AbstractClass obj = method(clz);
```

Of course, you can inline the construct as

```
AbstractClass obj=method(Class.forName(classNameStr).asSubclass(AbstractClass.class));
```

but it should be obvious why I wouldn’t recommend it.